# AEM Maven Failed to execute which is to install com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, aem

I am doing a tutorial in AEM the wknd one. I cloned from github. After running `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackagePublish` for publish instance, I get below error. I followed the suggestion in HELP but it didnt fix the problem.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:1.0.2:install (default-cli) on project aem-guides-wknd.ui.apps: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:1.0.2:install (default-cli) on project aem-guides-wknd.ui.apps: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

UPDATE:

Maven and Java versions:

[image]

Comment: Network issue: `s: Connection refused (Connection refused` ?

Comment: are you sure that your AEM server is up and running and reachable within your network?

Comment: @Pakira i think this one is my problem Im trying to rune AEM as service right now

Answer (score 0):

Use `aem.host` and `aem.port` to override the default localhost:4502 values used in the maven configuration (unless you have modified them already).

Comment: No actually I havent. Where can i find this maven config?

Comment: Open the root `pom.xml`, and look for: 


   <properties>
        <aem.host>localhost</aem.host>
        <aem.port>4502</aem.port>

But again, you can just the same command and override the default values, like this: `mvn clean install -D aem.host=myserver.com -D aem.port=8080 -P autoInstallPackage`